# stored procedure returns multiple resultsets but number of resultsets are not fixed

Tags: c#, stored-procedures, sqldatareader

I have a stored procedure which returns variable number of multiple resultsets. DataReader.NextResult() gives error if no next resultset exists . How to find whether next resultsets exists or not.

Comment: What error are you getting?  The docs say that if there are no more result sets, the NextResult method should simply return false.

Answer (score 4):

The NextResult() method returns true if there are more result sets - check that before making your next read

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.nextresult.aspx

Comment: On dataReader.NextResult() , I get error 'dataReader.NextResult()' threw an exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' bool {System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException} . This error I only get when there are no more resultsets.

Comment: The error is probably somewhere in your query.  Post a new question with a code listing, and the complete exception message.

Answer (score 0):

*(I know this is an old post, but hopefully this is helpful to someone!)*

You can do something like the following if you need to process an unknown number of result sets:

```
// Need to wrap the while loop in a do-while loop due to the way Read() works versus NextResult().
// Read() moves to the next record, if any, starting with the first record.
// NextResult() moves to the next result set, if any, starting with the second result set (i.e., first result set is used automatically).
do
{
    while (mySqlDataReader.Read())
    {
        // Do some processing here...for example:

        var rowValues = new object[mySqlDataReader.FieldCount];
        mySqlDataReader.GetValues(rowValues);

        foreach (var element in rowValues)
        {
            myStringBuilder.Append(element).Append(" | ");
        }

        myStringBuilder.AppendLine();
    }
}
while (mySqlDataReader.NextResult());
```